# Embeddable "NON-JDBC" SQL Database for Java

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

Is there a embeddable "NON-JDBC" SQL database? That is one that does not require running a server on the hardware as well (like SQLite).

Bonus points if it is pure java.

Comment: The only way to run SQL statements in Java is through JDBC. There is no such thing as "non-JDBC" for a SQL database. If you don't want to use JDBC you will need to use a NoSQL database.

Comment: In relation to your comment below "(I do not want to use JDBC because) I do not want to relearn how to write queries", it is completely baseless. JDBC is a wrapper so plain around the SQL that causes it to be abandonned when you need a portable application. You do SQL exactly the same way; but of course you must use java methods. The only real difference are preparedStatements, and they are one of the few good innovations of JDBC.

Comment: Anyway, if you don't want to use JDBC, you are completely free to write your own files...

Comment: I don't have this experience. Perhaps it was just the JDBC driver I was using.

Comment: @Chase, I updated my answer with an example SQL, so you may see how this looks. If you know SQL you don't need to relearn anything, ecept the particulars for the DB itself, but this is the same effert, whatever DB you may choose. I'm not aware of a nob JDBC DB for java anyway, unless you would implement some index flat files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather good database is `SQLite` which I started to use recently. You can create a db in memory, or on disk and it doesn't need any external installations.

**update**

@Chase, you seem to have a missconception about JDBC Queries. The only difference is, that you put the query in a string.

Here is a simple query with SQLite.

```
private String mSQL = "select count(1) from t\n";

private void foo()
{
    Connection con = getJDBCConnection();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    while (rs.next())
    {
        int n = rs.getInt("anzahl");
        System.out.println(n);
    }
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}
```

**update 2**

Here is a sample drop a table with an if clause, as you wanted to see. The actual create table statement is prepared somewhere else, so I just posted the line to show how it works.

```
statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists "+oTablename);
```

Comment: Yes. The answer was edited, and the JDBC was dropped, so I thought this was intentional, otherwise I wouldn't have recommended it.

Comment: But Chase doesn't want "JDBC" access (for whatever reason).

Answer (score 5):

There are several: [H2](http://h2database.com), [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (included with the Java SDK as "Java DB") and [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/)

H2 is pretty stable (but I wouldn't use 1.3.x for production code) and it can emulate almost any other SQL database (i.e. it can be configured to accept Oracle SQL syntax). Great for unit tests.

Derby is a Java-version of DB2. It's a bit more clumsy to use but ready for production.

HSQLDB is an older embeddable pure-Java database. I used that a lot until I met H2.

**EDIT** H2 supports `IF NOT EXISTS` and many other useful features. Note that things like that aren't part of JDBC. JDBC just sends strings to the database. But every database has its own SQL dialect and its own feature set; there is little that JDBC can do about this.

If you look for something that makes many databases behave similarly, you should look at [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/). You should also consider this when you care about quality.

Comment: You still use JDBC to access HSQL and Derby, isn't it? I ask because I still do not understand the reason of the "non-jdbc" requisite

Comment: I think they mean "doesn't need a JDBC driver JAR". I edited the question; we'll see soon whether I'm right.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Hmmm, I wouldn't make such an edit without knowing the requirements from the OP. After all, the answers are quite different.

Comment: Non-JDBC. I dislike the JDBC SQL syntax. It is unusable for me. I don't want to relearn how to write queries.

Comment: @Chase: "*I don't want to relearn how to write queries*" - so why do you want to use a SQL database then? That does not make sense. You either want to use SQL or you don't.

Comment: @Chase, what do you mean by "relearn"? I'm using SQLite and I use the same SQLs which I also use in the actual query. I think you may be confusing it with DAO or something, because you execute simple strings

Comment: @Devolus: I didn't say "relearn". Chase said that in his/her comment.

Comment: @Devolus Can you show me, because its not accepting most of my standard queries. I can't even use "IF NOT EXISTS" on a table create.

Comment: @Chase no, the JDBC driver will forward the SQL statements to your DBMS without altering it. Maybe you confuse JDBC with JPQL (query language for JPA)?

Comment: @Chase, I added an addtional example with an `drop if` statement straight from my codebase. When I want to debug SQLs I simply print them to the console and throw them directly into the DB, so there is no funky interface in between. I seem to rember some strange methods but I think that was with DAO objects from Microsoft. Not sure though.

Comment: @Chase: JDBC just gives you a way to talk to a database. It doesn't say anything about the SQL syntax and features. If you want `IF NOT EXISTS`, then you need to select an SQL database that support this. But you will still be talking to it via JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

[Sqlite4Java](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/) is a free java wrapper for SQLite. It is not a JDBC Driver.

It has binaries for Mac OS X, Windows, Linux and Android.